# Inequality on Functions of Bounded Variations

Tags: inequality, bounded-variation

The following discussions were based on Schwabik's book, entitled "Generalized Ordinary Differential Equations", pp.26-29.

Let $\delta$ be a positive function defined on $[a,b]$. We say that $D=\{([\alpha_{j-1},\alpha_j],t_j)\}_{j=1}^k$ is a **$\delta$-fine partition** of $[a,b]$ if $D$ is a partition of $[a,b]$ and for each $j=1,\dots,n$, $$t_j\in [\alpha_{j-1},\alpha_j]\subset (t_j-\delta(t_j),t_j+\delta(t_j)).$$

Let $f,g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be functions which are of bounded variations on $[a,b]$. Then $f,g$ are regulated. For each $\epsilon>0$, we put
$$N=\{t\in(a,b):|f(t^+)-f(t)|\geq \epsilon, |f(t)-f(t^-)|\geq \epsilon\}$$
where $f(t^+)$ and $f(f^-)$ are the one sided limits of $f$. Then $N$ is finite. For each $t\in [a,b]$, there is $\delta_1(t)>0$ such that if $x\in(t,t+\delta_1(t))$ then
$$|f(x)-f(t^+)|<\epsilon \mbox{ and }|g(x)-g(t^+)|<\epsilon$$
and if $x\in(t-\delta_1(t),t)$ then
$$|f(x)-f(t^-)|<\epsilon \mbox{ and }|g(x)-g(t^-)|<\epsilon.$$

For each $t\in [a,b]$, we set
$$\delta_2(t)=\mbox{dist}(t,N) \mbox{ for $t\notin N$}$$
and
$$\delta_2(t)=\delta_1(t)\mbox{ for $t\in N$}.$$

The symbol $\mbox{dist}(t,N)$ stands for the distance of the point $t$ from the set $N$. We define a positive function $\delta$ on $[a,b]$ as follows: For each $t\in [a,b]$, set $\delta(t)=\mbox{min}\{\delta_1(t),\delta_2(t)\}.$ Now, let us suppose that $D=\{([\alpha_{j-1},\alpha_j],t_j)\}_{j=1}^k$ is a $\delta$-fine partition of $[a,b]$.

**Question:** If we assume that $\alpha_{j-1}<t_j<\alpha_j$ whenever $t_j\in N$, then why is it that

$$\sum_{j=1}^k |f(t_{j}^{+})-f(t_j)|\cdot |g(t_{j}^{+})-g(\alpha_j)|+ \sum_{j=1}^k |g(t_{j}^{+})-g(t_j)|\cdot |f(t_{j}^{+})-f(\alpha_j)| + $$ $$+\sum_{j=1}^k |f(t_{j}^{+})-f(\alpha_j)|\cdot |g(t_{j}^{+})-g(\alpha_j)|+ \sum_{a\leq t<b, t\notin N}  |f(t^{+})-f(t)|\cdot |g(t^{+})-g(t)|$$
$<\epsilon TV(f,[a,b])+ 3\epsilon TV(g,[a,b])$?

Any tips on how to prove it are very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality is false as stated. Let $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}0 & x\leq 1/2 \\ (1-\eta)\epsilon & x>1/2 \end{cases}
\qquad
g(x) = \begin{cases}0 & x\leq 1/2 \\ 1 & x>1/2 \end{cases}
$$
where $0 < \eta \ll 1$. Then $N = \varnothing$, and $\{([\alpha_{j-1},\alpha_j],t_j)\}_{j=1}^k$ given by $k=2$, $\alpha_j = j/2$, $t_1 = t_2 = 1/2$ is a $\delta$-fine partition (note that $\delta(1/2)$ can be arbitrarily large), and we find that
\begin{align}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}\sum_{j=1}^k \lvert f(t_{j}+)-f(t_j) \rvert \cdot \lvert g(t_{j}+)-g(\alpha_j) \rvert
+ \sum_{j=1}^k \lvert g(t_{j}+)-g(t_j) \rvert \cdot \lvert f(t_{j}+)-f(\alpha_j) \rvert \\
&\qquad\quad + \sum_{j=1}^k \lvert f(t_{j}+)-f(\alpha_j) \rvert \cdot \lvert g(t_{j}+)-g(\alpha_j) \rvert
+ \sum_{a\leq t<b, t\notin N}  \lvert f(t+)-f(t) \rvert \cdot \lvert g(t+)-g(t) \rvert \\
&= 4 \lvert f(\tfrac12+) - f(\tfrac12) \rvert \cdot \lvert g(\tfrac12+) - g(\tfrac12) \rvert \\
&= 4 (1-\eta) \epsilon \\
&> (1-\eta) \epsilon^2 + 3\epsilon \\
&= \epsilon TV(f) + 3\epsilon TV(g)
\end{align}
when $\epsilon$ and $\eta$ are sufficiently small.

---

I presume that you're trying to follow the proof of [Corollary 1.23](https://books.google.com/books?id=8JZ1DwxmKDsC&lpg=PP1&dq=isbn%3A9810212259&pg=PA26#v=onepage&q=1.23%20Corollary&f=false) in which your inequality is a step. There are two ways to salvage this. One would be to merge the two neighboring intervals $[\alpha_{j-1},\alpha_j]$ and $[\alpha_j, \alpha_{j+1}]$ whenever $t_j = t_{j+1}$, as demonstrated on page 29 during the justification of the assumption that $\alpha_{j-1} < t_j < \alpha_j$ whenever $t_j \in N$. Doing so will allow you to assume that $t_1 < t_2 < \dotsb < t_k$. With this additional assumption I believe $\epsilon TV(f) + 3\epsilon TV(g)$ is a valid bound. The proof is a bit tricky.

The other, which I prefer, would be to prove a different bound. As is evident from the last paragraph of page 29, what's required is not the specific bound $\epsilon TV(f) + 3\epsilon TV(g)$, but rather *a* bound of the form $C\epsilon$ where $C>0$ is a constant independent of $\epsilon$ and the partition. I found it significantly easier to prove the weaker bound $\epsilon TV(f) + 4\epsilon TV(g)$.

The first step for either of these two approaches would be to write out what it means for $\{([\alpha_{j-1},\alpha_j], t_j)\}_{j=1}$ to be a $\delta$-fine partition for the particular $\delta$ given in the question; this should give you bounds on some of the factors appearing in the four sums as long as a certain condition is met. Then think about what can be done when that condition isn't satisfied.

---

In more detail, for reference (don't look yet if you're looking to prove things yourself):

For each $j$, either $t_j < \alpha_j$ or $t_j = \alpha_j$. Consider the two cases separately:

- $t_j < \alpha_j$. Since $D$ is $\delta$-fine, $\alpha_j \in (t_j, t_j + \delta_1(t_j))$. It follows from the definition of $\delta_1$ that $\lvert f(\alpha_j) - f(t_j^+)\rvert < \epsilon$ and $\lvert g(\alpha_j) - g(t_j^+)\rvert < \epsilon$.
- $t_j = \alpha_j$. Then by assumption $t_j \notin N$ so
  $
  \lvert f(\alpha_j) - f(t_j^+)\rvert
  = \lvert f(t_j) - f(t_j^+)\rvert
  < \epsilon.
  $

It follows immediately that the second and the third sums are each bounded by $\epsilon TV(g)$.

That the fourth sum is also bounded by $\epsilon TV(g)$ follows from the definitions of infinite sums, total variation, and $N$.

It remains to consider the first sum. We split the sum into the two cases $t_j < \alpha_j$ and $t_j = \alpha_j$ from before:
\begin{multline}
\sum_{j=1}^k \lvert f(t_{j}+)-f(t_j) \rvert \cdot \lvert g(t_{j}+)-g(\alpha_j) \rvert \\
\begin{split}
&= \sum_{\substack{j \in \{1, \dotsc, k\} \\ t_j < \alpha_j}} \lvert f(t_{j}+)-f(t_j) \rvert \cdot \lvert g(t_{j}+)-g(\alpha_j) \rvert
+ \sum_{\substack{j \in \{1, \dotsc, k-1\} \\ t_j = \alpha_j}} \lvert f(t_{j}+)-f(t_j) \rvert \cdot \lvert g(t_{j}+)-g(\alpha_j) \rvert \\
&< \epsilon \sum_{\substack{j \in \{1, \dotsc, k\} \\ t_j < \alpha_j}} \lvert f(t_{j}+)-f(t_j) \rvert
+ \sum_{\substack{j \in \{1, \dotsc, k-1\} \\ t_j = \alpha_j}} \lvert f(t_{j}+)-f(t_j) \rvert \cdot \lvert g(\alpha_{j}+)-g(\alpha_j) \rvert.
\end{split}
\end{multline}
To complete the proof of the weaker bound, note that the above is bounded by $\epsilon TV(f) + \epsilon TV(g)$.

To obtain the original bound, on the other hand: Observe that my additional assumption $t_j < t_{j+1}$, together with the $\delta$-fineness of $D$, implies that if $\alpha_j = t_j$, then $\alpha_j \in (t_{j+1} - \delta_1(t_{j+1}), t_{j+1})$, and in particular $\lvert g(\alpha_j) - g(t_{j+1}-) \rvert < \epsilon$. Hence
\begin{multline}
\sum_{\substack{j \in \{1, \dotsc, k-1\} \\ t_j = \alpha_j}} \lvert f(t_{j}+)-f(t_j) \rvert \cdot \lvert g(\alpha_j+)-g(\alpha_j) \rvert \\
\begin{split}
&\leq \sum_{\substack{j \in \{1, \dotsc, k-1\} \\ t_j = \alpha_j}} \lvert f(t_{j}+)-f(t_j) \rvert \cdot \bigl(\lvert g(\alpha_j+)-g(t_{j+1}-) \rvert + \lvert g(t_{j+1}-)-g(\alpha_j) \rvert \bigr) \\
&< \epsilon \sum_{j=1}^k \lvert g(\alpha_{j-1}+)-g(t_j-) \rvert
+ \epsilon \sum_{\substack{j \in \{1, \dotsc, k-1\} \\ t_j = \alpha_j}} \lvert f(t_{j}+)-f(t_j) \rvert.
\end{split}
\end{multline}
The sum of the first and the third sums from the question is therefore bounded as follows:
\begin{multline}
\sum_{j=1}^k \lvert f(t_j+)-f(t_j) \rvert \cdot \lvert g(t_j+)-g(\alpha_j) \rvert
+ \sum_{j=1}^k \lvert f(t_j+)-f(\alpha_j) \rvert \cdot \lvert g(t_j+)-g(\alpha_j) \rvert \\
\begin{split}
&< \epsilon \sum_{j=1}^k \lvert f(t_{j}+)-f(t_j) \rvert
+ \epsilon \sum_{j=1}^k \bigl( \lvert g(\alpha_{j-1}+)-g(t_j-) \rvert + \lvert g(t_j+)-g(\alpha_j) \rvert \bigr) \\
&\leq \epsilon TV(f,[a,b]) + \epsilon \sum_{j=1}^k TV(g,[\alpha_{j-1},\alpha_j]) \\
&= \epsilon TV(f,[a,b]) + \epsilon TV(g,[a,b]).
\end{split}
\end{multline}

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention of this question. May I know some details Sir? Why is it that $\sum_{j=1}^{k}|f(t_j^+)-f(t_j)|\leq TV(f,[a,b])$. I got confused because $t_{j}^+$ is not a division point of $[a,b]$  since by notation, $f(t_{j}^+)=\lim_{x\to t_{j}^+}f(x).$

Comment: @juniven Assuming that $t_1 < \dotsb < t_k$ as I said we can, consider $\epsilon_1,\dotsc,\epsilon_k > 0$ such that $t_1 + \epsilon_1 < t_2$ and so on. Then $\sum_{j=1}^k \lvert f(t_j + \epsilon_j) - f(t_j) \rvert \leq TV(f)$ by the definition of total variation. Taking the limits $\epsilon_j \to 0$ gives that inequality. Intuitively, this says that jump discontinuities are accounted for in the total variation.

Comment: Ah okay, I got it already. Many thanks to you Sir.